# Functions with If

Tags: python, string, function, if-statement, type-conversion

**Question:** How can I update the my code so that when I type "perfect" as a score, it returns with the words, "bad score?" In trying to do so in my current code, I get the following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/renelyncruz/Desktop/Bellevue College Work/CS 101/Cruz_FunctionsWithIf.py", line 1, in 
>       grade_rate=float(input("Please enter a score between 0.0 and 1.0."))
>   ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' perfect'*

My current code is as follows:

```
grade_rate=float(input("Please enter a score between 0.0 and 1.0."))

def computegrade(grade_rate):

    if grade_rate<0.0 or grade_rate>1.0:
        return ('Bad score')

    elif grade_rate>=0.9:
        return ("Your grade would be an A! Congratulations!")

    elif grade_rate>=0.8:
        return ("Your grade would be a B! Congratulations!")

    elif grade_rate>=0.7:
        return ("Your grade would be a C. You should try harder.")

    elif grade_rate>=0.6:
        return ("Your grade would be a D. Keep trying!")

    elif grade_rate<0.6:
        return ("Your grade would be an F. Work harder!")

    else :
        return ('Bad score')

try:
    grade=computegrade(grade_rate)
    print(grade)

except ValueError as e:
    print("Bad Score")
```

Comment: Move `grade_rate=float(input("Please enter a score between 0.0 and 1.0."))` below `try:`

Comment: Doing that would bring up the error that I haven't defined grade_rate yet. Also, adding the same line under my "try:" would produce the same result as my original result.

Comment: Perhaps I should be more clear. Remove it from the top, and place it as the first statement underneath the try block, above `grade=computegrade(grade_rate)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may catch this as follows:

```
try :
    grade_rate=float(input("Please enter a score between 0.0 and 1.0."))
except ValueError :
    print( "bad score" )
```

and there's no point in wrapping this:

```
grade=computegrade(grade_rate)
print(grade)
```

in a `try/except` block, since it's very unlikely to throw anything.

Comment: The `try`-`except` method works. Did you run the wrong code or do you have multiple places where you do that input and you forgot to use exception handling on one of those?

Comment: I have solved it now, but lenik, it turns out I do need to wrap this:
grade=computegrade(grade_rate)
print(grade)
If I don't, the code will not work properly.

Comment: Right. You will not get a `ValueError` but the code won't work because `grade_rate` isn't defined if you get an exception in the call to `float`.